# React: add focus to first child of a component which is a wrapper

Tags: reactjs, focus, use-effect

If I have a component like

```
const Comp = ({children}) => {

    //some code
    return (
        <div> 
            {children}
        </div>
    )

}
```

and then call it like

```
<Comp>
    <input onChange={...} />
    <input onChange={...} />
</Comp>
```

How can I change the focus to the first input field of this component when the component renders, from within the `Comp` component.

Ideally I would like to have a useEffect function or something which looks something like

```
useEffect(() => {
   thisComponent.firstChild.focus()
})
```

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647061/how-do-i-access-refs-of-a-child-component-in-the-parent-component

Comment: @ChrisSu That wont work because I can't set the ref to the children like that, because they are all passed in as `children`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two things, `useRef` and `useEffect`, `useRef` for getting target element  ref, and `useEffect` for handling focusing when then component renders.

`children` in a component props is an array, so you can manipulate it, you can use `index` to get which `child` element you want to set ref, and then call `focus()` by ref in `useEffect`:

```
function App(props) {
  const firstChildRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(firstChildRef.current) {
      firstChildRef.current.focus()
    }
  }, [firstChildRef])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {props.children.map((child, index) => {
        if(index === 0) {
          return {...child, ref: firstChildRef};
        }
        return child;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit]

Comment: What if the first child isn’t focusable, like a label or something, or another div wrapper

Comment: @Sam You could do a conditional checking, if the method exists, call the method, otherwise do other things to handle the situation.

Comment: Im pretty sure that useEffect hook doesn't  look safe listen to ref changes. So why the [firstChildRef]?